Ubuntu strixpoint support
I just recieved my new laptop which I bought for my computer science study. The laptop is the asus zenbook S 16 (UM5606WA-RK003W). I know it's overkill, but I wanted a laptop that would be able to last me quite a bit into the foreseeable future. For my study I needed to dualboot it with ubuntu. This was not a problem, but I'm noticing some issues which might be related to the laptop being very recent. The laptop contains the new amd strix point CPU alongside a radeon 880m. Now I know that the cpu will only be recognised since linux kernel 6.11-rc2. Is there any chance that 6.11 will land in 24.04.1? And what about drivers for my gpu? Because scrolling feels a lot less responsive then it should.
And some probably more nooby questions:

my internal speakers are recognised by the os and are reportedly playing audio, but I'm not hearing anything
my keyboard has backlights which, although the toggle button gives a pop up on ubuntu is in a constant slow pulse and never actually is affected by the button

sorry if this is a jumbled mess. I'm familiar with ubuntu through WSL, but never actually dual booted it.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

Realistically speaking, it may take another year (release 25.04) for Ubuntu to support this laptop. Linux 6.11 will be released in September. Fedora 41 will be released in October, and it would most likely have kernel 6.11. You can try that. While Ubuntu 24.10 will also be released in October, it may not have this kernel (but Ubuntu 25.04 will definitely have kernel 6.11 or later).

Ubuntu 22.04.1 will use the 6.8 kernel, as the next kernel upgrade for the LTS comes from 24.10 which is expected to use the 6.10 kernel that can be seen currently (6.10.0-15.15 ); but even if that changes (on 24.10); it won't be packaged for 24.04 until it reaches 24.04.2 as has been done the last decade+ (refer HWE docs), the packaging won't start until after 24.10 has released & thus kernel is known.

This question is similar to: How do I know if a laptop will work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
